# Xcode Disposing memory - images taking up too much memory and won't deallocate

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, memory, modal-dialog

Updated:

I have a lot of view controllers and the app is image heavy. Each is presented modally at the moment. I'm disposing of all my images,timers etc and whatever else in viewwilldisappear on every view controller, but when it segues it just seems to be allocating memory continually on top of the previous VC and everything else without getting rid of a single thing which eventually crashes it (i know this will happen with modal segues).
How can i change this? I have tried embedding my controllers in a navigation controller but the same problem is still happening where it will not release any of the images on the controllers. Here is an example of my code and where i'm getting rid of what i've created in VWD. VWD is definitely being called. Hopefully this makes sense to someone, thanks in advance.

```
@interface AnimationStartViewController ()

@end

@implementation AnimationStartViewController




SystemSoundID skipintro;



-(void) viewDidLoad
{


 [super viewDidLoad];



(sleep(2.5));
NSString *music=[[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"1Animation" ofType:@"mp3"];
animationaudio=[[AVAudioPlayer alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:music] error:NULL];
animationaudio.delegate= (id)self;
animationaudio.numberOfLoops=-1;
[animationaudio play];


NSURL *skipintroURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Click" ofType:@"mp3"]];
AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID((__bridge CFURLRef)skipintroURL, &skipintro);


//Text Timers

text1timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.0 target:self selector:@selector(Text1show:) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
text2timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.0 target:self selector:@selector(Text2show:) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
text3timer =  [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.0 target:self selector:@selector(Text3show:) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
text4timer =  [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.0 target:self selector:@selector(Text4show:) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];

text5timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.0 target:self selector:@selector(Text5show:) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
text6timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.0 target:self selector:@selector(Text6show:) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
text7timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.0 target:self selector:@selector(Text7show:) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
text8timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.0 target:self selector:@selector(Text8show:) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];


logotimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.0 target:self selector:@selector(showlogo) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
pushtimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:20.0 target:self selector:@selector(performthesegue) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];



//Text Timers invalidate


stoptext1timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:6.0 target:self selector:@selector(invalidatetext1) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
stoptext2timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:6.0 target:self selector:@selector(invalidatetext2) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
stoptext3timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:6.0 target:self selector:@selector(invalidatetext3) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
stoptext4timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:6.0 target:self selector:@selector(invalidatetext4) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];

stoptext5timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:14.5 target:self selector:@selector(invalidatetext5) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
stoptext6timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:14.5 target:self selector:@selector(invalidatetext6) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
stoptext7timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:14.5 target:self selector:@selector(invalidatetext7) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
stoptext8timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:14.5 target:self selector:@selector(invalidatetext8) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];


moveAnimationTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.05 target:self selector:@selector(moveAnimation) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

stopAnimationTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:20.0 target:self selector:@selector(StopAnimation) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];



}



//scrolling Animation.

- (void) moveAnimation {
animation.center = CGPointMake(animation.center.x, animation.center.y -2);

}


//Stop

- (void) StopAnimation {
[moveAnimationTimer invalidate];
moveAnimationTimer = nil;


}




//====================== Text animations





//AttheGateof

-(void)Text1show:(NSTimer *)timer {


[UIView animateWithDuration:2.0 delay:0.70
                    options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve
                 animations:^ {
                     Atthegateof.alpha = 1.0f;
                 }
                 completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                     Atthegateof.alpha = 1.0f;
                 }];
}



//MidnightZoo

-(void)Text2show:(NSTimer *)timer {



[UIView animateWithDuration:2.0 delay:1.75
                    options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut
                 animations:^ {
                     MidnightZoo.alpha = 1.0f;
                 }

                 completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                     MidnightZoo.alpha = 1.0f;
                 }];
}



//Who lives inside

-(void)Text3show:(NSTimer *)timer {

[UIView animateWithDuration:2.0 delay:2.9
                    options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut
                 animations:^ {
                     Wholivesinside.alpha = 1.0f;
                 }
                 completion:^(BOOL finished) {

                 }];
}


// Thedeepblackblue

-(void)Text4show:(NSTimer *)timer {

[UIView animateWithDuration:2.0 delay:3.3
                    options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut
                 animations:^ {
                     Thedeepblackblue.alpha = 1.0f;
                 }
                 completion:^(BOOL finished) {

                 }];
}



//unlockthegate

-(void)Text5show:(NSTimer *)timer {

[UIView animateWithDuration:2 delay:7
                    options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut
                 animations:^ {
                     Unlockthegate.alpha = 1.0f;
                 }
                 completion:^(BOOL finished) {

                 }];
}
 //tocomeinside

-(void)Text6show:(NSTimer *)timer {
//music 'high' point
[UIView animateWithDuration:2 delay:7.5
                    options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut
                 animations:^ {
                     Tocomeinside.alpha = 1.0f;
                 }
                 completion:^(BOOL finished) {

                 }];
}
//behindeachlock

-(void)Text7show:(NSTimer *)timer {

[UIView animateWithDuration:2 delay:8.2
                    options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut
                 animations:^ {
                     Behindeachlock.alpha = 1.0f;
                 }
                 completion:^(BOOL finished) {

                 }];
}
//something hides

-(void)Text8show:(NSTimer *)timer {

[UIView animateWithDuration:2 delay:8.7
                    options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut
                 animations:^ {
                     Somethinghides.alpha = 1.0f;
                 }
                 completion:^(BOOL finished) {


                 }];
}




 //======================================= Get rid of text




//indvalidate 1
-(void)invalidatetext1 {
[stoptext1timer invalidate];
stoptext1timer = nil;

[UIView animateWithDuration:0.7 delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut animations:^{
    Atthegateof.alpha = 0;

} completion:^(BOOL finished) {

    [Atthegateof removeFromSuperview];

}  ];


}

//invalidate 2
-(void)invalidatetext2 {
[stoptext2timer invalidate];
stoptext2timer = nil;
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.7 delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut animations:^{
    MidnightZoo.alpha = 0;

} completion:^(BOOL finished) {

    [MidnightZoo removeFromSuperview];

}  ];



}

//invalidate 3
-(void)invalidatetext3 {
[stoptext3timer invalidate];
stoptext3timer = nil;

[UIView animateWithDuration:0.7 delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut animations:^{
    Wholivesinside.alpha = 0;

} completion:^(BOOL finished) {

    [Wholivesinside removeFromSuperview];


}  ];



}

//invalidate 4
-(void)invalidatetext4 {
[stoptext4timer invalidate];
stoptext4timer = nil;

[UIView animateWithDuration:0.7 delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut animations:^{
    Thedeepblackblue.alpha = 0;

} completion:^(BOOL finished) {

    [Thedeepblackblue removeFromSuperview];


}  ];


}


//invalidate 5
-(void)invalidatetext5 {
[stoptext5timer invalidate];
stoptext5timer = nil;

[UIView animateWithDuration:0.75 delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut animations:^{
    Unlockthegate.alpha = 0;

} completion:^(BOOL finished) {

    [Unlockthegate removeFromSuperview];

}  ];

}
//invalidate 6
-(void)invalidatetext6 {
[stoptext6timer invalidate];
stoptext6timer = nil;

[UIView animateWithDuration:0.75 delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut animations:^{
    Tocomeinside.alpha = 0;

} completion:^(BOOL finished) {

    [Tocomeinside removeFromSuperview];


}  ];




}
//invalidate 7
-(void)invalidatetext7 {
[stoptext7timer invalidate];
stoptext7timer = nil;

[UIView animateWithDuration:0.75 delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut animations:^{
    Behindeachlock.alpha = 0;

} completion:^(BOOL finished) {

    [Behindeachlock removeFromSuperview];

}  ];



}
//invalidate 8
-(void)invalidatetext8 {
[stoptext8timer invalidate];
stoptext8timer = nil;

[UIView animateWithDuration:0.75 delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut animations:^{
    Somethinghides.alpha = 0;

} completion:^(BOOL finished) {

    [Somethinghides removeFromSuperview];

}  ];

}




//=======================================



-(void)showlogo {

[UIView animateWithDuration:2.0 delay:16.0
                    options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut
                 animations:^ {

                     zoowhologo.alpha = 1.0f;
                 }
                 completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                     zoowhologo.alpha = 1.0f;
                 }];

}





-(void)performthesegue {

[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"pushgototitle" sender:nil];


}


- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{


}



- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
[super viewWillDisappear:animated];


NSLog(@"viewilldisappear was called");


[animationaudio stop];

[text1timer invalidate], text1timer=nil;
[text2timer invalidate], text2timer=nil;
[text3timer invalidate], text3timer=nil;
[text4timer invalidate], text4timer=nil;
[text5timer invalidate], text5timer=nil;
[text6timer invalidate], text6timer=nil;
[text7timer invalidate], text7timer=nil;
[text8timer invalidate], text8timer=nil;

[stoptext1timer invalidate], stoptext1timer=nil;
[stoptext2timer invalidate], stoptext2timer=nil;
[stoptext3timer invalidate], stoptext3timer=nil;
[stoptext4timer invalidate], stoptext4timer=nil;
[stoptext5timer invalidate], stoptext5timer=nil;
[stoptext6timer invalidate], stoptext6timer=nil;
[stoptext7timer invalidate], stoptext7timer=nil;
[stoptext8timer invalidate], stoptext8timer=nil;

[logotimer invalidate], logotimer=nil;
[pushtimer invalidate], pushtimer=nil;
[moveAnimationTimer invalidate], moveAnimationTimer=nil,
[stopAnimationTimer invalidate], stopAnimationTimer=nil;

AudioServicesDisposeSystemSoundID(skipintro);

[Atthegateof removeFromSuperview], Atthegateof=nil;
[MidnightZoo removeFromSuperview], MidnightZoo=nil;
[Wholivesinside removeFromSuperview], Wholivesinside=nil;
[Thedeepblackblue removeFromSuperview], Thedeepblackblue=nil;
[Unlockthegate removeFromSuperview], Unlockthegate=nil;
[Tocomeinside removeFromSuperview], Tocomeinside=nil;
[Behindeachlock removeFromSuperview], Behindeachlock=nil;
[Somethinghides removeFromSuperview], Somethinghides=nil;
[topper removeFromSuperview], topper=nil;
[skip removeFromSuperview], skip=nil;

[zoowhologo removeFromSuperview], zoowhologo=nil;
[animation removeFromSuperview], animation = nil;
[stopanimation removeFromSuperview], stopanimation = nil;

}


- (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
[super viewWillDisappear:animated];
[self.presentingViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];


}


- (IBAction)skipintro:(id)sender {

AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(skipintro);
[animationaudio stop];
[pushtimer invalidate];
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"pushgototitle2" sender:self];


[self.presentingViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];

}
```

Comment: Is your `viewWillDissapear` method Called ? Please post the code so we can help

Answer (score 0):

Several things.

If you present view controllers modally, they get stacked up one on top of the next, and none of them get released until you dismiss them. Make sure you're not creating a new instance of a previous view controller and pushing it modally instead of dismissing back to the desired VC.

Second,

It used to be that when a view controller was moved off-screen, it's view hierarchy was unloaded, freeing up most of the memory it took. That's no longer true. (and hasn't been for quite a few major iOS releases. I want to say this changed in iOS 4, but am not positive of this.)

If a view controller is in memory, so is it's entire view hierarchy, including any images that are installed in image views inside those views.

You can indeed implement a viewWillDisappear method and use that method to nil out any data structures that are not installed in your view hierarchy. You then need to implement a viewWillAppear method that reloads those data structures.

If your app presents a series of view controllers modally, and then the user "unrolls" each view controller and returns back to the root view controller then your method of using modal presentation is reasonable. (Using a navigation controller and a stack of pushed view controllers might be better, but you claim not.) Both approaches keep a stack of all the previously visited view controllers active and in memory.

If instead your UX has your user move from VC to VC without the need to return, you should instead implement your own custom segue that dismisses the previous view controller, or perhaps uses a child view controller that it swaps for another one as the user navigates.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, this is very helpful, I still have the same problem however. The app begins with a few title views which you do not need to return to, and thereafter each view is unrolled and the user will return to a root view. I have embedded my view controllers in a navigation controller with push segues which seems better but as you say both approaches keep previously visited VCs in memory. What I want to do is remove the view controllers from memory after they have been viewed (and reload them again if need be), but it seems to be holding on to the view